# Yii2 данные из связанной таблицы

Tags: mysql, yii2, activerecord

Есть таблица записей(items), таблица изображений(images), и таблица связей(items_images). Т.е. получается связь один ко многим(у одной записи несколько изображений). Вид таблицы items_images

```
item_id | image_id | sort
```

Нужно получить значение поля sort для каждого изображения, делаю так

```
public function getImages()
{
    return $this->hasMany( Image::className(), ['id' => 'image_id'])
        ->viaTable('{{%items_images}}', ['item_id' => 'id'] )
        ->leftJoin('{{%items_images}}', ['{{%items_images}}.item_id' => $this->id])
        ->onCondition(['item_id' => $this->id] )
        ->select('*');
}
```

Выводит все поля с модели Image, т.е. как и нужно, а поля c таблицы `items_images` нет :(

---

Поправил запрос

```
public function getImages()
{
    return $this->hasMany( Image::className(), ['id' => 'image_id'])
        ->viaTable('{{%items_images}}', ['item_id' => 'id'] )
        ->leftJoin('{{%items_images}}', '{{%items_images}}.image_id = {{%images}}.id')
        ->select('*');
}
```

Если выбирать как массив, т.е.

```
Item::find()->where( 'id = :id', [ 'id' => $id ] )->with('images')->asArray()->one()
```

Выбирает, как нужно.

Если убрать `asArray()`, то item_id, image_id и sort не возвращает. Почему так ?

Answer (score 2):

Так работает

```
public function getImages()
{
    return $this->hasMany( Image::className(), ['id' => 'image_id'])
        ->viaTable('{{%items_images}}', ['item_id' => 'id'] )
        ->leftJoin('{{%items_images}}', '{{%items_images}}.image_id = id')
        ->asArray()
        ->select('*');
}
```

По–другому непонятно как сделать.